# Tomcat 5.5 virtual host with appbase

Tags: java, tomcat, virtualhost

I'm trying to create a virtualhost in Tomcat 5.5. Up till now  I've created the Host entry

```
<Host name="www.nikoslianeris.gr" appBase="test"
       unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
       xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
directory="test" prefix="mydoamin_access_log." suffix=".txt"
pattern="combined" resolveHosts="false"/>
</Host>
```

and everything is ok with that. The problem is that when I put my app in the appbase directory nothing happens. I mean, I can see from the admin console the new virtual host bat when I type the url nothing happens. I don't know what the problem might be! I found many tutorials on the subject and did what they said but nothing happens!

Answer (score 0):

just brainstorming, but have you mapped www.nikoslianeris.gr to your local machine in your hosts file or a local DNS? ie any request to that domain should result in the request being sent to your machine, then the request gets sent to tomcat, and only then does the virtual host settings above kick in.

In theory you can test if this is the case using ping or traceroute on that domain, or by telnetting to your local machine on the Tomcat port and writing a sample HTTP request and also specify the "Host:www.nikoslianeris.gr" in the HTTP header. In theory.